# Ninject MVC5 Registering Generic Repository not working no more

Tags: c#, asp.net, repository, ninject, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am using MVC5 and have an IGenericRepository and an GenericRepository

I bind them like so:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).To(typeof(IGenericRepository<>));
```

In MVC3 an MVC4 this worked like a charm.
Now in MVC4 i get an error:

> Error activating IGenericRepository{UserProfile} o matching bindings
>   are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong?

Thanx

Comment: What is the error which appears when you do it the correct way (as Shane T stated)?

Comment: Error activating IGenericRepository{UserProfile} o matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

It's so strange that it gives me this error. In other Mvc3 or Mvc4 i do not have this problem. I just register my services and that's it. Now it asks for repositories inherting form genericrepository in order to let all work

Comment: Please create a minimal test project which reproduces the issue and then create an issue on Ninjects issue tracker, with details on the issue and a link to test reproducing project. https://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues?state=open

Answer (score 4):

Binding should be otherway around?

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IGenericRepository<>)).To(typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```